# What is the difference between high and normal Ray Tracing in the Resident Evil 4 remake?

Tags: pc, graphics, resident-evil-4-2023

I started playing the game recently, and it has optimisation issues, especially in VRAM usage. However, I noticed Ray Tracing has a high and normal setting, that can be changed to reduce VRAM. I can’t notice much difference, so what exactly is the main difference between these settings?